# How can I get df.isnull() for a single column of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
missing_data = df.isnull()
```

gives me details for every column in my pandas data frame.
Can i get it for a single column (`'Class'`) in my df, without having to split a string etc? - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the entries with nulls in one column, try this.

`missing_data = df[df['Class'].isnull()]`